# asp.net gridview if cell row value is equal then

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am populating a datatable, then binding it to a gridview. Now I'm reading the rows in the grid and coloring the row `if value = [x]`.

The thing when I try to display on the page the row that is colored im getting it duplicated. 
Lets say i have colored 1 row but the `response.write` will be like 100 times the same result. 
Below is my code, hope someone can help :

```
protected void gv1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    string alert = Request.QueryString["check"];

    // loop over all the Rows in the Datagridview 
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gv1.Rows)
    {
        // if condition is met color the row text 

        if (gv1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text.ToString() == alert)
        {
            Session ["fn"] = gv1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Text;
            gv1.Rows[0].ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }
        Response.Write(Session["fn"]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected void gv1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    string alert = Request.QueryString["check"];

        if (e.Row.Cells[0].Text.ToString() == alert)
        {
            Session ["fn"] = e.Rows.Cells[2].Text;
            e.Rows.ForeColor = Color.Red;

        Response.Write(Session["fn"]);
        }
}
```